# Fedora 26 has UTC shifted +3 hours

Tags: fedora

I have two computers installed from the same source, but one of them exhibits weird-to-me time issues.

```
sudo timedatectl
[sudo] password for mmucha: 
      Local time: Mon 2018-04-09 13:58:51 CEST
  Universal time: Mon 2018-04-09 11:58:51 UTC
        RTC time: Mon 2018-04-09 11:58:51
       Time zone: Europe/Prague (CEST, +0200)
 Network time on: yes
NTP synchronized: no
 RTC in local TZ: no
```

The timezone is correct, and correctly applied to UTC, but UTC is three hours wrong. It's weird, that NTP synchronized is not installed. So I installed NTP and ran it, starting it as `systemctl start ntpd`. I also did 'enable'. However, after boot:

```
sudo systemctl status ntpd
● ntpd.service - Network Time Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/ntpd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

Maybe this is an issue? Anyway, after starting it manually again, I got a running service and:

```
[mmucha@embNotebook ~]$ sudo timedatectl
      Local time: Mon 2018-04-09 14:04:47 CEST
  Universal time: Mon 2018-04-09 12:04:47 UTC
        RTC time: Mon 2018-04-09 12:04:46
       Time zone: Europe/Prague (CEST, +0200)
 Network time on: no
NTP synchronized: yes
 RTC in local TZ: no
```

But whatever I try, it does not sync UTC.

What is the correct way, and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: so I called 'timedatectl set-time 15:25' to get 'sooner' normal time, and not surprisingly  this changed localtime reported by timadatectl, but also Universal time and RTC time. Seems little bit selfcentric! Like if universal time is revolving around my laptop...